# Extract Attribute name from XML File, given the ParentNode's Attribute Value in C#

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

Given the following XML File,

```
    - <CommandTiming Name="Architecture.Dome">
      <Sample Name="run1" EllapsedTime="627" /> 
      <Sample Name="run2" EllapsedTime="636" /> 
      <Sample Name="run3" EllapsedTime="650" /> 
      <Sample Name="run4" EllapsedTime="626" /> 
      <Sample Name="run5" EllapsedTime="643" /> 
      </CommandTiming>
```

I would like to extract the EllapsedTime for run1, run2, run3, run4 and run5, given the CommandTiming Name = "Architecture.Dome"

I want an array with the values 627, 636, 650, 626, 643.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(
 "<CommandTiming Name='Architecture.Dome'>" + 
        "<Sample Name='run1' EllapsedTime='627' />" +
        "<Sample Name='run2' EllapsedTime='636' /></CommandTiming>");
var values = doc.XPathSelectElements("CommandTiming[@Name='Architecture.Dome']/Sample")
    .Select(v => v.Attribute("EllapsedTime").Value);
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/rundotnet?code=CNN24938

Comment: Thanks a lot! The following code worked for me! 
   
<code>    var RunTime = from XMLFile in 
    doc.Descendants("CommandTiming") where 
    XMLFile.Attribute(attributeName).Value == i.Value select 
    XMLFile.Descendants("Sample").Attributes(attribute) <code>

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(
 "<CommandTiming Name='Architecture.Dome'>" + 
        "<Sample Name='run1' EllapsedTime='627' />" +
        "<Sample Name='run2' EllapsedTime='636' /></CommandTiming>");//etc    
var elapsedTimes = doc.Root.Elements().Attributes("EllapsedTime").
    Select(e => e.Value).ToArray<string>();
```